# iOS device float-right issue with header item

Tags: android, ios, css, angular, ionic3

I have a problem with an `iOS` device with a header. When I used below `HTML` it works perfectly fine on Android device.

[**stackblitz Editor URL**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-cvxdi8?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

[**stackblitz App URL**](https://ionic-cvxdi8.stackblitz.io)

*.html*

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>
      <span>Budget</span>
      <ion-icon name="ios-add-outline" float-right></ion-icon>
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

*Android UI:* No issues.

[image]

But on an iOS device, it is not working. Header's center alignment is fine. But the problem is with the `+` sign. I need to show it like an android device. In other words `float-right`. Can you tell me how to achieve that?

iOS device:

[image]

Comment: It is because `ios` and `md` mode have different styles. You can find it out by inspecting into element. But there is an easier way, that is showing `md` mode in all devices by adding `mode="md"` to `ion-navbar` and `ion-title`

Comment: No. It won't work since my client needs different styles on 2 platforms. @Duannx Any other method?

Comment: Have you already tried with a layout like this?: `<ion-title>...</ion-title>
<ion-buttons end> <!-- your button here! --> </ion-buttons>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>
      Budget
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
        <button ion-button icon-only clear>
           <ion-icon name="ios-add-outline"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ionbuttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```